# converting plain text into textbox format

Tags: vb.net

I am searching for code that converts plain text to this format

I mean

If for example there is a plain text = **v6.23b 12 Full**

so i want that it converts this text to this format

Format

**version 6.23 Build 12**

that's it . the word "**full**" should not be seen in the format

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
Dim oldText As String = "v6.23b 12 Full"
Dim newText As String = oldText.Replace("v", "version ").Replace("b", " Build").Replace("Full", String.Empty)
```

Note that you'll have issues if there are other "v"s or "b" in the string.

Comment: it worked but there may be other situation too ..  It will if there is same text but i want that it should not show  any word after "12" as there may be a word "full"  or "trail"   . so plz help me

Comment: Then you'll need to put your programming skills to use. If you always only want the first 10 characters (or whatever), then code a `SubString` in first. If you always want to remove 'full', code that, if you always want to remove 'trial', code that.

Comment: Ok than , i got it what i should do .. thanks for guiding :)

Answer (score 0):

Forcing myself to learn Regular Expressions, so this seemed like a good exercise...

I used these two sites to figure these out:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx

Here's my version using Regex:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim version As String = "v6.23b 12 Full"
        Debug.Print(version)

        ' Find a "v" at the beginning of a word boundary, with an optional space afterwards,
        ' that is followed by one or more digits with an optional dot after them.  Those digits with an optional dot
        ' after them can repeat one or more times.  
        ' Change that "v" to "version" with a space afterwards:
        version = Regex.Replace(version, "\bv ?(?=[\d+\.?]+)", "version ")
        Debug.Print(version)

        ' Find one or more or digits followed by an optional dot, that type of sequence can repeat.
        ' Find that type of sequence followed by an optional space and a "b" or "B" on a word boundary.
        ' Change the "b" to "Build" preceded by a space:
        version = Regex.Replace(version, "(?<=[\d+\.?]+) ?b|B\b", " Build") ' Change "b" to "Build"
        Debug.Print(version)

        ' Using a case-insensitive search, replace a whole word of "FULL" or "TRIAL" with a blank string:
        version = Regex.Replace(version, "(?i)\b ?full|trial\b", "")
        Debug.Print(version)
    End Sub

End Class
```